# Angularjs Kendo Chart Tooltip field "undefined error"

Tags: angularjs, kendo-chart

I'm trying to setup tooltips for my chart.  The value is a percentage, but I want the "actual" number not the percentage to show.  The field name is "moduleCount" and it does have the correct values in it.  However, when I hover over the chart I receive an "'moduleCount' undefined" error from Angular.  I assume I am not defining the tooltip correctly since 'moduleCount' is defined and has value.

My HTML:

```
<div kendo-chart
                     k-series-defaults="{type: 'column', labels:{visible: true, background: 'transparent', field: 'modulePercentage', format:'p0', template: '#= value#%'}}"
                     k-series="[{field: 'modulePercentage', colorField: 'BackGroundColor', name: 'SSQScore', type: 'pie'}]"
                     k-plot-area="{margin:{top: 5, left: 25, right: 25, bottom: 5}}"
                     k-category-axis="{field: 'Score', labels:{font: 'bold 8px sans-serif', rotation: '-45'},majorGridLines:{visible: true}, line:{visible: true}}"
                     k-value-axis="{majorGridLines: {visible: true}, visible: true}"
                     k-tooltip="{visible: true,format: '{0}',template: '#=moduleCount #'}"
                     k-data-source="contractorStatus">

                </div>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out.  I needed to include "dataItem" with the name of the field.  The working definition is:

```
 k-tooltip="{visible: true,format: '{0}',template: ' #=dataItem.moduleCount # '}"
```